# Cannot install gems on RVM JRuby gemset: SocketError: initialize: name or service not known (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rubygems, rvm, jruby

I'm trying to install JRuby and Ruby on Rails (or "JRuby on Rails") with RVM  on GNU/Linux Debian, but I'm getting some error. This is what I have done.

First of all, I made these installations (because of the requirements that are displayed with **rvm requirements**):

```
sudo apt-get install curl g++ openjdk-6-jre-headless
sudo apt-get install ant openjdk-6-jdk
```

Then (the error is at the end as you can see):

```
pablo@martigomez:~$ rvm install jruby --1.9
jruby-1.6.7.2 - #fetching 
Cloning from git://github.com/jruby/jruby.git, this may take a while depending on your connection...
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/pablo/.rvm/repos/jruby/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 197772, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (45785/45785), done.
remote: Total 197772 (delta 139597), reused 196103 (delta 138126)
Receiving objects: 100% (197772/197772), 108.15 MiB | 102 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (139597/139597), done.
HEAD is now at 8e849de Tag ERB specs that depend on default runs sharing a scope.
From git://github.com/jruby/jruby
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Copying from repo to src path...
jruby-1.6.7.2 - #ant jar

jruby-1.6.7.2 - #ant jar  -Djruby.default.ruby.version=1.9
Building Nailgun
jruby-1.6.7.2 - #installing to /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7.2
jruby-1.6.7.2 - adjusting #shebangs for (jrubyc jirb_swing jirb jgem rdoc ri spec autospec testrb ast generate_yaml_index.rb).
jruby-1.6.7.2 - #importing default gemsets (/home/pablo/.rvm/gemsets/)
Copying across included gems
pablo@martigomez:~$ rvm jruby
pablo@martigomez:~$ ruby -v
jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-09-24 26e08ba) (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_18) [linux-amd64-java]
pablo@martigomez:~$ rvm --create use jruby@r328
Using /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2 with gemset r328
pablo@martigomez:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***


pablo@martigomez:~$ gem install rails --version 3.2.8
WARNING:  Error fetching data: SocketError: initialize: name or service not known (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
WARNING:  Error fetching data: SocketError: Network is unreachable (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: rdoc requires json (~> 1.4); treetop requires polyglot (>= 0), polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
```

I have searched but at the moment I haven't found something that helps. It is very strange that there are no gems. This is my first time with JRuby, but as I was searching on the web, when you install JRuby you suppose to have some basic gems installed, right? So what could it be the problem and the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Odd...  I have exactly the same setup as you, followed the exact same steps, and it worked.  Are you still getting that error?  Could it have been a temporary problem with connection to rubygems?

Comment: I think that may be the problem... I was searching and I found that I have to change the DNS (use the Google ones). I will try right now